# Designing JQuery / Ajax sites backwards compatible w' no-JavaScript browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Does anyone know a good place to look for basic principles and tutorials on designing a JQuery rich websites, but which would still work in browsers that either don't support JavaScript or have it disabled?

If that's even possible, in practical terms..

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. So no js = no jQuery

Comment: *["If you can imagine an](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) [entire book](http://www.google.com/search?q=progressive+enhancement) [that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)*

Comment: @PranavKapoor - I know that, but I don't think you read my question thoroughly

Comment: @josh3736 - Yes I can imagine, which is why I asked to point me to such a "place" (aka. a book, site, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you look at all this, you should be aware of a few things.

Historically, there were lots of reasons to make things work without JS:

- SEO. Googlebot ran much like Lynx
- Mobile devices. Hardly any, if any at all would run JS
- Paranoid users who turn off JS
- Corporate restrictions
- Accessibility - screen readers etc.

If we look at todays landscape, things are different

- Googlebot evaluates JS. In my own testing I've found that Googlebot can make ajax requests via jQuery code, and include text inserted into the page in it's results.
- Mobile devices run better browsers than desktops for many users (i.e. Android Phone + IE8 user)
- Noscript etc allow you to whitelist sites, though hardly anyone uses it anyway
- Some corporations likely still ban JS, but again, it's minimal
- Accessibility is getting better, and in many ways it's not an issue, but users may still be using older versions that don't deal with JS well.

This means that you are making a site without JS for accessibility reasons. This lets you concentrate much more on the experience you are creating without JS.

In short, you should ensure that anything that happens via AJAX can also happen without. This usually means modifying your serverside code so that anytime it generates JSON, it can also create the whole page the JSON is to be inserted into (i.e. if you have a button that loads text into a div, you should have an actual page with that view in).

An alternative approach is to carefully provide a different version of the app targeted at users without JS. Many old mobile sites are “good” examples of this.

Comment: Good points, I was also wondering if it's even worth the extra effort of doing so..

Comment: Well, that depends on if you don't like people who have disabilities. I'd say that you should ensure that your app is at least usable for people who are blind, or need other AT. Unlike browsers, you can't demographically assume things about this – tech people might use Chrome/Firefox rather than IE, but you can't assume they are not blind, for instance. http://www.w3.org/WAI/Policy/ outlines the laws for different countries, though you should really be keeping accessibility in mind anyway.